# Как посчитать сумму последних значений в столбце фрейма данных?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Есть фрейм данных, в столбце цифры. Впрос: как посчитать сумму за последние 2 значения? А как посчитать сумму значений за 5 последних ячеек без последних двух? Или сумму первыз 3х?

Пример:

```
df
name count
A      3
B      0
C      1
D      5
E      2 
F      1
G      5
```

В данном случае, последние 2 значения по сумме будут равны 6. А последние 5 без последних двух равны 8. А первые 3 равны 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как посчитать сумму за последние 2?

```
In [10]: df.iloc[-2:, df.columns.get_loc("count")].sum()
Out[10]: 6
```

> как посчитать сумму значений за 5 последних ячеек без последних 2х?

```
In [11]: df.iloc[-5:-2, df.columns.get_loc("count")].sum()
Out[11]: 8
```

> Или сумму первых 3х?

```
In [12]: df.iloc[:-3, df.columns.get_loc("count")].sum()
Out[12]: 9
```

Comment: @Nikolay_Smirnov а кто ж его знает? нам ведь, в отличие от вас, не известно, что такое 'sep'.

Comment: @Nikolay_Smirnov, исправил ответ...

Comment: Можно всё же попроще `df.iloc[-2:]['count'].sum()` )

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, можно и так. Просто у меня выработалась привычка так не делать из-за ["chained indexing" проблемы](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) при присвоении. Но если присваивать/изменять данные не нужно, то это вполне рабочее решение)